# Divide two integers resulting into a float

Tags: programming-sequence

Suppose I want to divide two integer variables and put the result into a float.
In order to prevent integer division do I have to program like this:

```
    int i = 6312;
    int j = 258;
    float f;
    f = i;
    f = i/j;
```

Or can I straightforward program like below and the compiler makes sure it is handled the 'proper' way:

```
    f = i/j;
```

Comment: why don't you run a test?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your first block of code? Did you mean to write `f = f/j;`? Otherwise, (a) why bother assigning `f = i;`? and (b) the last line of the first block is exactly the same as the line in the second block... So the question doesn't make much sense... unless you made a typo...

Comment: @Greenonline: you are correct, in the first block of code I should have written f = f/j;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the integers to float before doing the calculation.

```
float f = float(i) / float(j);
```

or

```
float f = (float) i / (float) j;
```

Always be clear how the calculation should be done, so the compiler will do what you want it to do.

Comment: or `float f = (float) i / j;`

Comment: @Juraj, that relies on the compiler to do a float calculation when a float and a int are involved. I prefer to make it clear for someone reading the code and for the compiler what is going on without having to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

As Arduino is C++, you should *really* use a [static cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/2628257), to be technically accurate. However, for Arduino code it probably doesn't really matter.

So either

```
float f = static_cast< float >(i) / static_cast< float >(j);
```

or

```
float f = static_cast< float >(i) / j;
```

**Note**: Using a static cast on each operand, rather than just one, is  useful to quiet any warnings about the loss of precision with `int` to `float`, which typically needs to form a rounded `float` for large `int` values.

See [C++ int float casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5456801/4424636) for more info.

---

Just to add to Jot's answer: Strictly speaking, it should be pointed out that `(float)` is C, whereas `float()` is C++.

---

Also, as you had meant to write in your question:

```
int i = 6312;
int j = 258;
float f;
f = i;
f = f/j;
```

Yes, that would work. However, even though it seems quite elegant, it could cause confusion later in time, when someone else examines the code - unless you added a comment explaining why.

it is probably best to keep the code simple and obvious (for debugging purposes) unless you are deliberately intending to obfuscate the code.